# Proc Export to update excel sheet with format/Layout in SAS

Tags: sas

I want to export the SAS data set into existing EXcel sheet (or update the existing value).
The code I used for this :

```
PROC EXPORT DATA=data_total
  OUTFILE= " pathr"
  DBMS=XLSX REPLACE;
  SHEET="Data Total";
RUN;
```

(I am using SAS 9.4)

However when I do this, while the data is copied, there are two issues that I am facing

1. The format of the data changes . For example, 0.02% changes to 0.0002068 and some other values to 0% to 2.352E-03 etc
2. My destination file has a particular layout (eg: header is color coded). But PROC EXPORT replaces the layout with a plain one.

Can someone please help me in solving this issue?

Thank You

Comment: did u try changing format in the dataset right before exporting it?

for example, if you declare `format` in the beginning of project, when you export dataset in the end SAS sometimes 'forgets' format

Comment: In my opinion, a good practice for this type of work is to have an unformatted tab where you export your raw data to, and next to it a nicely formatted tab with customised layout and formatted columns that links back to the raw data tab.

Comment: PROC EXPORT will overwrite it, there's no way around that. I would suggest using @VojtaF approach OR switching your entire report to ODS EXCEL if that's an option. But I don't think you can export to an already created file. You would have to have the entire process be in ODS Excel but it's pretty powerful these days.

Comment: @VojtaF Thank you. Can you elaborate more on this? Do you mean writing a macro in the worksheet to update the format? Or throwing the raw data to a new tab and then referencing the data to the existing formatted tab?

Comment: Also is there any way to export ODS HTML output to the existing workbook? While I am able to export it to an excel sheet but not to an existing workbook. Any alteratives?